# How to add automatically row on paste in Handsontable at last row?

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net-core, handsontable

I am creating a web application in .Net Core and for excel we are using Handsontable and it works fine.

Now when the user copy more than one row and only one place is there(last row remaining) then it shows us an error.

We have `non-commercial-and-evaluation` license key for educational purposes.

We also add this in our code for auto insert rows.

```
fillHandle: {
    autoInsertRow: true,
},
```

If anyone has answer then please let me know it help me a lot.

Comment: If you would include the error and relevant code that would help us tremendously.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Questions seeking debugging help ("why isn't this code working?") must include the desired behavior, a specific problem or error and the shortest code necessary to reproduce it in the question itself. Questions without a clear problem statement are not useful to other readers. See: [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).